# Call jQuery on Dynamically Created Textboxes (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following jQuery function that dynamically creates 5 collapsibles (inside a collapsible):

```
$(function() {
var key, value;
var Storage = 5
// loop through local storage
for (var i = 0; i < Storage; i++) {
// retrieve the key
key = i;
// set the field from the key
value = "Medicine" + i.toString();

//$("#medListDiv").show();
var text = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right">' + '<h2>' + value + '</h2>' + '<input id="number' + i.toString() + '" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />' + '<textarea cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Type any directions written on your prescription for the above medicine." ></textarea></div>';
 $("#medListDiv div:first").append(text);
 }

 $('#medListDiv').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
 $('#medListDiv').trigger("create");

});
```

The code above sets a different `id` to each `textbox` (notice `'<input id="number' + i.toString() + '" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />'`).

My issue now is that I want these textboxes to only accept NUMBERS (whole digits only - no decimals) so I came up (found) with the following function that works perfectly when a "static" id is given:

```
$("#number0").on('keypress', function(ev) {
var keyCode = window.event ? ev.keyCode : ev.which;
//codes for 0-9
if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
    //codes for backspace, delete, enter
    if (keyCode != 0 && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 13 && !ev.ctrlKey) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
}
});
```

I've been trying to make this function take any `id` depending on which `textbox` the users selects.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PU4UC/) I made only shows 5 `collapsibles` but my original program takes user inputs and the number of medicines can vary. Notice that the first `Quantity` textbox wont allow any letters. I would like all the `Quantity` textboxes to behave the same way.

I have also tried a different function, adding `var qtyID = $(this).attr(i);` so removes any inputs that arent numbers, but it doesn't seem to do the work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var qtyID = $(this).attr(i);
    $("#number" + qtyID).keypress(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    $(this).val(value);
    });
});
```

I have also tried placing the whole function inside the main function, but didn't help at all.
Basically all I want is to be able to `get` the dynamically created `id` from those `textboxes` so I can call a little function on them, but regarless of the countless examples I saw online on how to do this, I can't manage to get it working.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `.ready()` in JQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your only calling the function on your first quantity input.  Instead of selecting the input by ID select it by class.

Add a `number class` to each input.

```
var text = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right">' + '<h2>' + value + '</h2>' + '<input id="number' + i.toString() + '" class="number" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />' + '<textarea cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Type any directions written on your prescription for the above medicine." ></textarea></div>';
```

Then call your function on the `class` instead of the `id` Which applies to all your quantity inputs and not just the first one.

```
$(".number").on('keypress', function(ev) {
    var keyCode = window.event ? ev.keyCode : ev.which;
    //codes for 0-9
    if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
        //codes for backspace, delete, enter
        if (keyCode != 0 && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 13 && !ev.ctrlKey) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PU4UC/1/

Comment: Thank you for this solution, yes I was aware that I was only calling on the first quantity input, did it that way to show what I wanted for all. This solution sure solves this particular problem. Thank you! :) - Also, if its not too much to ask, is there a reason why the function above won't work on a mobile emulator? (Opera, to be specific). It does work ok on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation:

```
$('#medListDiv').on('keypress', '#number0',  function(ev) {
```

You're handler is being bound at run-time and doesn't know about these dynamically created elements. Bind to an element that does exist at run.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('body').on('keydown', ".number", function (event) {

             if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                 // Allow: Ctrl+A
                     (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||

                 // Allow: home, end, left, right
                     (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
             } else {
                 // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                 if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                 }
             }
         });
     });
```

HTML:

```
<td><input type=text id=Qty_' + ID + '  class="number"/></td>'
```